# Proving $\sigma_1(n) \phi(n)>n/2$

Tags: number-theory, totient-function

I need to prove that $\sigma_1(n) \phi(n)$ is less or equal than $n^2$ and greater than $n/2$. I managed to prove the first part but now I need some help on proving that it's greater than $n/2$. I got to $\sigma_1(n) \phi(n)=\prod_{i=1}^s p_i^{2 \alpha_i}-p_i^{\alpha_i-1}$.

$n=\prod_{i=1}^s p_i^{\alpha_i}$.

Comment: What do you mean by $\sigma(n)$?  The usual notation has a subscript, $\sigma_k(n)=\sum_{d|n}d^k$.  Which $k$ did you have in mind?  Please edit your post to clarify.

Comment: In this case $k=1$.

Comment: So, edit your post to say that.  As a general note, since the left hand is an  arithmetic function and the right hand is close, it should be enough to prove it for prime powers.

Answer (score 1):

From $\sigma_1(n)\geq n$ and $\phi(n)\geq1$ we have $\sigma_1(n)\phi(n)\geq n>\frac{n}{2}$.

Answer (score 0):

What you have is enough to prove the second part, consider
$$2\frac{\sigma_1 (n) \phi (n)}{n} = 2 \prod_{i = 1}^s \frac{p_i^{\alpha_i +1} - 1}{p_i}$$
Since $\alpha_i \geqslant 1$, you have
$$2\frac{\sigma_1 (n) \phi (n)}{n} \geqslant 2 \prod_{i = 1}^s \frac{p_i^2 - 1}{p_i} = 2 \prod_{i = 1}^s \frac{(p_i - 1)(p_i+1)}{p_i} \geqslant 2$$

Maybe am I mistaken?

Answer (score 0):

The estimate follows directly from $\sigma(n)\ge n$. Actually, we have
$$
\frac {6}{\pi^2} < \frac{ \sigma(n)\phi(n)}{n^2} < 1
$$
for all $n>1$. Did you really mean $\sigma(n)\phi(n)>\frac{n}{2}$? It looks like a typo, because we immediately have $\sigma(n)\phi(n)\ge n$, so why bother with $\frac{n}{2}$?